# The Watchkit app I'm debugging gets deleted from the watch automatically

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, watchkit, apple-watch

I can build my Watchkit app to my Apple Watch and debug it just fine. It's a watch-only app, but it appears in the app list of the "Watch" app on the paired iPhone as it should.

The problem is that after a few days the app just disappears from the watch and I have to go back to XCode to re-install it to the Watch.

Why is this happening and is there a way to prevent it or set the expiration period to be longer?

Comment: This happened to me before when the developer profile I used for signing the app wasn't marked as trusted on the paired iPhone.

Comment: How do I get the iPhone to trust the profile? I feel like I've clicked "Trust" on the phone & watch every time the warning pops up.

Comment: Go to Settings>General>Profiles&Device Management>Developer app and choose your developer ID and Trust.

Comment: Apparently it's Settings>General>Device Management>Developer app and it says that I am trusted and lists the app as being from me, so I guess something else is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I am on WatchOS 10.3 and still faced this issue.  What solved it for me is In Target/General/Deployment info:

- Make sure that "supports running without IOS app installation" is checked
- In App Icons:  make sure that "include all app icon sets" is checked